# how to use partialtriggers, selectOneRadio and inputText in adf

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using selectOneRadio to select which inputText will be available. So, I have this variant:

```
<af:selectOneRadio 
                                   id="id1"
                                   autoSubmit="true"
                                   binding="#{page.bindingSelect}"
                                   value="#{page.radioBtnValue}">
                  <af:selectItem label="show1" value="show1" />
                  <af:selectItem label="show2" value="show2"/>

<af:inputText id="id2" 
                              value="#{bindings.input1.inputValue}"                            
                              partialTriggers="id1"
                              binding="#{page.input1}" 
                              disabled="#{page.radioBtnValue!='show1'}">                                   
</af:inputText>
<af:inputText id="id3" 
                              value="#{bindings.input2.inputValue}"                            
                              partialTriggers="id1"
                              binding="#{page.input2}" 
                              disabled="#{page.radioBtnValue!='show2'}">                                   
</af:inputText>
```

and bean for button:

```
public String newCommitTest() {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = 
            bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        Object result = operationBinding.execute();
        if (!operationBinding.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("---------"+getInput1().getValue()) ;
        System.out.println("---------"+getInput2().getValue()) ;
        return null;        
    }
```

as result I have
getInput1=null
getInput2=null

but, If I didn't use partialTriggers this variant works fine and in db puts correct value...

Can anybody helps?
jdeveloper 10.1.3
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the text of the commandbutton?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.slideshare.net/stevendavelaar/18-invaluable-lessons-about-adfjsf-interaction

It is very useful and worth to read. It clears a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

For update atributes I used:

```
getMyInputText().setDisabled(true);
getMyInputText().setReadOnly(true);
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getMyInputText());
```